# Samsung galaxy not displaying menu

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scroll

I have created an android program.It has a menu button and I published it in Google play.But in my phone Samsung Galaxy not showing that menu .I tried it in LG Nexus 4 it works fine .Then I tried in different tablets and works fine .Micro max ninja not showing menu.

Also I want to know about menus of different style .How to enable horizontal scrolling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What kind of Menu button? The one that is displayed on the Action bar or digital buttons below? Because it might not be displayed because the phone might have a dedicated, physical menu button.
As from the [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html):

> The action overflow in the action bar provides access to your app's less frequently used actions. The overflow icon only appears on phones that have no menu hardware keys. Phones with menu keys display the action overflow when the user presses the key.

Comment: Menu that is displayed in Action bar

Comment: Then ensure the other phone doesn't have a physical menu button, if it does, that's why it doesn't get displayed.

Comment: No it has no physical button

Comment: Which Galaxy is exactly?

Comment: It does have a dedicated menu button... It's a capacitive touch button, the one at the left. That's why the action bar doesn't draw it. Try touching it and the menu should open just fine.