# Appcompat three dot menu not displayed on Android < 3

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar, compatibility, android-appcompat

I would like to display three dot menu in my app also on devices with android lower than version 3.0.

But on devices with Android version < 3 is menu displayed only after menu button pressing.

I tried to find any wotking solution for this but none from them working from me. 
What is most easy way how to solve it on all devices?

Im using appCompat_v7_3

Many thanks for any advice.

Here is  code of menu and activity.

**menu main_activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/last_position_menu_btn"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_drawer"
        android:title="@string/last_positions"
        android:showAsAction="always"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/settings_menu_btn"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_drawer"
        android:title="@string/app_settings"
        android:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

**onCreateOptionMenu from main Activity**

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity, menu);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

Comment: try this stack Overflow question [link][1]     


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23261125/android-oncreateoptionsmenu-is-not-displaying

Comment: Thanks, but removing the line  android:targetSdkVersion="18" from manifest is not solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your 3.0 device has a hardware menu button. Android does not display the overflow icon when there is a hardware menu button present.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21037428/samsung-galaxy-not-displaying-menu) or [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html).